# How to create a function that will be optimized away (to noop) in release?

Tags: swift

Basically, what would be an equivalent to:

```swift
#if DEBUG
func myDebugFunction(arg: String) {
  /// function body using `arg`
}
#endif
```

if I don't want to wrap every use with

```swift
#if DEBUG
myDebugFunction(potentiallyExpensiveFunctionCallToOptimizeAway())
#endif
```

like eg. `assertionFailure()` does?

The best I can think of is to use `@autoclosure` for arguments, and `#if DEBUG` to empty the body, but is this enough for the Swift compiler to optimize away the call completely (and thus not call `potentiallyExpensiveFunctionCallToOptimizeAway` in release mode)?

```swift
func myDebugFunction(arg: @autoclosure () -> String) {
  #if DEBUG
  /// function body using `arg`
  #endif
}
```

Or does Swift has some way to mark the function to be optimized away including the arguments?